# Big O Notation of an expression

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

If I have an algorithm that takes 4n^2 + 7n moves to accomplish, what is its O? 
O(4n^2)?
O(n^2)?

I know that 7n is cut off, but I don't know if I should keep the n^2 coefficient or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should drop any coefficients because the question is really asking "on the order of", which tries to characterize it as linear, exponential, logarithmic, etc...   That is, when n is very large, the coefficient is of little importance.

This also explains why you drop the +7n, because when n is very large, that term has relatively little significance to the final answer.  If you are familiar with calculus, you might say lim n->inf(4*n^2+7n) ~= lim n->inf(4*n^2) ~= lim n->inf(n^2)

You can also think about this in a graphical sense...   that is, if you graph the function 4n^2 + 7n for larger and larger values of n, a mathematician might say "it looks like n^2".  Granted, it would have to be a fairly liberal mathematician, as this isn't a rigorous statement, but that's basically what O(...) is trying to convey.

Answer (score 11):

The coefficients aren't relevant in Big O notation, so it's just O(n<sup>2</sup>).  [As Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> [...] the coefficients become irrelevant if we compare to any other order of expression, such as an expression containing a term n<sup>3</sup> or n<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: sorry a noob here, but what about the 7n. n is surely a variable.

Comment: No, somewhat counter-intuitively, 7n is irrelevant.  As Wikipedia explains: If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.

Comment: It's not that counter intuitive, I think...   Think about f(n)=n^2+n.  f(10) = 110  f(100) = 10100  f(10000) = 100010000.  You can see that the +n becomes less and less significant to the final answer.

Comment: It's not counter-intuitive at all.  Always think of these things with numbers like a billion billion - how much would n^2 contribute to the final number over 7n?  7n would hardly be a blip.

Comment: But what if I have an algorithm that is 4n^2 + 7n and other that is 16n^2 + 7n? With O notation, they will both look O(n^2) when in fact one is clearly the best!

Comment: @devoured elysium: you are clearly overlooking the fact that these are ASYMPTOTICAL analysis. Read the final note on my answer.

Comment: If it's just for values that are unimaginable big, why bother with big O notation first? I don't get it.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone reading or writing about complexity of algorithms should know exactly what the [Landau Symbols](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandauSymbols.html) and [asymptotic notations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticNotation.html) are, otherwise they don't really understand what is going on, or simply have an approximate (and often misleading) idea.

To simplify (a lot), let `f` and `g` be two functions `f : N -> N` and `g : N -> N`. We say that `f is O(g)` if and only if there's a constant `M > 0` such that `|f(n)| < M|g(n)|`, for all `n > M`. That is, more informally, starting from a big value of `n`, all the values `f(n)` are smaller than a multiple of `g(n)` (ie, `g` *grows faster* than `f`).

That definition is equivalent to

```
f is O(g) <==> There is K >= 0 such that lim{n -> +oo} |f(n)|/|g(n)| = K
```

So, let's take `f(n) = 4n^2 + 7n` and `g(n) = n^2`, and try to prove `f is O(g)` (I will omit `{n -> +oo}`):

```
lim |f(n)|/|g(n)| = lim f(n)/g(n) = lim (4n^2 + 7n) / n^2 = 4 + lim 7n/n^2 =
                  = 4 + lim 7/n = 4 + 0 = 4
```

This implies that there is a `M` such that `n > M ==> |f(n)| < M|g(n)|`, and thus `f is O(g)`.

So technically it is correct to say `4n^2 + 7n is O(4n^2)`, as it is correct to say `4n^2 + 7n is O(n^3)`, `4n^2 + 7n is O(e^n)`, and so on. But to be meaningful, we are interested in the lower bound. So if `f is O(e^n)` and `f is O(n^2)`, we are more interested into knowing that `f is O(n^2)`, since this is much more restrictive.

### VERY IMPORTANT note

What is extremelly important when choosing an algorithm is to understand that *big-O notations* refers to *asymptotic cases*, that is, when you consider **extremely, unimaginable huge inputs**, that can go well beyond the computational power available in the known universe (ie, infinite input sets, expressed mathematically by `{n -> +oo}`).

For practical uses (ie, not *so* huge inputs), when choosing an algorithm, sure, you will observe candidate algorithms *big-O notations*, but you must be sure that the chosen algorithm is well adapted (and performs better) for your (expected) input.

Finally, usually better performing algorithms are more difficult to understand and to implement properly. You must consider this fact as well when choosing an algorithm (ie, *is the time I will spend **debugging and fixing my implementation** of this algorithm considerably superior to the time I would have to wait with another algorithm, with a worse big-O notation?*. If so, you should consider the simpler, less efficient algorithm, as the overall solution would be more efficient).

Comment: While I appreciate the technical detail of your post, I'd say _working knowledge_ of what the notation means should be enough to use it to compare different algorithms (i.e. "reading")... I'd even go as far as to say that's kinda the whole point of the notation (most notations).

Comment: @Paul-Jan: I only partly agree. Not every O(n^2) algorithm performs worse than every O(n) algorithm in every situation, it depends on the size of the input, and THIS is what most people miss! So if you think "yeah, O(n) is better than O(n^2) *cuz*, say, 10 is less than 10^2", and then choose your O(n) algorithm, you might be making a huge mistake. Choosing algorithms is not for people who simply have a *working knowledge* of algorithm complexity and are barely able to understand a notation.

Comment: To complement my last comment, this is expressed by the `{n -> +oo}` part of the definition, that most people have no idea it is there (or its meaning...).

Comment: You might want to explain the very important note with a simple example: Big O memory use is nice, but your algorithm runs on a real computer, with a real maximum of memory. If the memory consumption is 300,000 n + 0.04n^2 bytes, the constant 300,000 will be the bottleneck, not the O(n^2)

Comment: @Stephan: yeah, I really want to add an example, but I'm looking for a "WOW!" real-world, common example, some kind of huge mistake that is made everyday without noticing.

Answer (score 6):

It's O(n^2). Constant factors "move into the O". You only keep the largest exponent since this is the one dominating. And you can leave out coefficients since when comparing different algorithms even very large coefficients result in smaller total numbers than having a larger exponent (with n large enough).

Answer (score 4):

A statement like

```
4n² + 7n = O(n²)
```

means that for some constant multiplier `c`, the expression `cn²` will eventually overtake `4n² + 7n`. It's technically not incorrect to leave the coefficient in there — `O(n²)` and `O(4n²)` mean the exact same thing, because any constant `c` for the former can be replaced by `c/4` for the latter. However, such a thing is less clear, possibly misleading, and definitely nonstandard.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, you would write O(4n²). It means that the complexity function of your algorithms behaves as n->4n² towards positive infinite.

But in computer science/algorithm, you would only write O(n²), which is sufficient to categorize your algorithm.