# What is the running time of two separate for loops vs. two nested for loops?

Tags: for-loop, runtime, big-o

In this example, I have two separate for loops. Is the running time O(num1 + num2)?

```
for(int i=0; i< num1 ; i++)     
{
   print i;
}

for(int i=0 ; i<num2 ; i++)
{
    print i;
}
```

And for this example, there is a nested for loop. Would the running time be O(num1*num2) because for each number in 0 to num1, you have to iterate from 0 to num2?

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<num1 ; i++)
 {
     for(int j=0 ; j<num2 ; j++)
     {  
         print i;
     }
}
```

Comment: Instead of worrying about big O right away, why don't you first calculate how many numbers will be printed by each of those snippets for a couple of values for `num1, num2`? That should give you some intuition.

Comment: The first example is O(n) and the second is O(n^2). Big-O notation indicates how the run time increases with the size of the input, you don't put the actual numbers in.

Comment: First Case is Num1+Num2 Big-O =O(n) and Second Case Num1*Num2 Big-O = O(N^2)

Comment: You should realize that the index variable in the second example shouldn't be `i` in both loops..

Answer (score 4):

You can be more general. Big-O notation isn't about finding exact values given your actual parameters. It is about determining asymptotic runtime. In this case, we can just replace num1 and num2 with n, where n is the upper bound of some interval starting at 0. Using this method, we would find the runtime of your first example to be O(n), and the second example would have a runtime O(n^2). The first example runs in linear time, and the second example is quadratic. You rarely need to go into more detail than this to categorize algorithmic runtime.

Comment: So, if `for(int i=0; i< num1 ; i++) { print i; }` is **O(n)** then why are two iterations still **O(n)**?  Wouldn't it be **O(n*2)** since you are iterating twice instead of just once?

Comment: While you are correct about the coefficient, Big-O notation does not include that level of detail. It only conveys the order of magnitude of runtime. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081846/big-o-notation-question